# "Give me it" is considered a mistake?

Tags: objects, indirect-objects, ditransitive-verbs

I usually say 'Give it to me please'. But I've heard a non English speaker mom who said to her baby girl 'Give me it'. Is it considered natural or it's a mistake?

Comment: "Give me it" and "Give it to me" are both fine.

Comment: It's not a mistake, necessarily, but "Give me it" is not very common. I would expect "give me that" or "give me [the object]" (or "give it to me").

Comment: @Katy, or just, "gimme!".

Comment: The construction is marginal or perhaps regional. This has also been discussed on ELU https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9305/is-it-incorrect-to-say-give-me-it

Answer (score 1):

A ditransitive construction with a personal pronoun as a direct object is marginal at best.

> If O<sup>d</sup> is a personal pronoun, the prepositional construction is favoured, especially if the other NP is not a pronoun — examples like *<sup>%</sup>I gave Kim it* are inadmissible for most speakers, especially in AmE. (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002: 310)

However, I have certainly heard "gimme it"; but it is best avoided, since for some speakers it is still unnatural.

Comment: Gimme this or that or it is not unnatural. It is fast speech or in some cases uneducated speech. Even the snottiest U speaker will say: Gimme that when speaking very fast.

Comment: @Lambie I said it is unnatural to SOME speakers. You're not the only native speaker that currently exists. "Gimme it" is regional but is becoming widespread, and reportedly common in Northern and Eastern England ([Upton, 2006](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?start=30&q="give+me+it"+&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5#d=gs_qabs&u=%23p%3DMIBUMhoj98QJ)). "Give me that" is of course grammatical in any dialect, because "that" is not a personal pronoun.

Comment: Ditransitivity with personal pronouns is quite common. "Give Me Zen" for instance.

Comment: ""Give me that" is of course grammatical in any dialect, because "that" is not a personal pronoun." But "me" is.

Comment: @Accumulation It is the OD (Direct object). "Me" is a personal pronoun, but it is an indirect object. There is nothing wrong with "Give me Zen".

Comment: This has also been discussed on ELU. The top answer agrees that it is not natural in Standard English @Lambie https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9305/is-it-incorrect-to-say-give-me-it

Comment: I really don't care what the top answer says. "Not natural" is not a linguistic observation. Anything spoken by a human being is  natural. Because it certainly is not animal or mineral.

Answer (score 0):

It is a correct construction of verb (Give), indirect object (me), and direct object (it).

Comment: In formal grammar, indirect objects require a preposition, making this informal.

Comment: No.  Indirect objects are perfectly formal, and do not require preposition.